# white window with samsung magician

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I bought new ssd and install Samsung Magicain 5 from official site. I got white window when started app. Windows 10 x64. How can I fix it?

[image: magician window]

Comment: update GPU driver, maybe the tool is WPF based which uses HW acceleration.

Comment: I have the same problem with version 5 and 5.1.

Answer (score -1):

It works with Samsung Magician 4.9.5 and BIOS set to AHCI or IDE and not RAID.